# Apache automatic redirection when referrer is ABC

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

there is this domain that is hotlinking my css files. This is an example in the log:

> [Thu Jul 14 15:17:14 2011] [error] [client 190.79.200.109] File does
>   not exist: /www/old.css, referer: http://www.somedomain.com/start.php

I want to redirect all non-existant files that come from that somedomain.com domain to another url so they stop doing that. How do i do that via htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do [using mod_rewrite](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-hotlinking):

> This code should be placed in the htaccess file in the image directory you wish to protect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain.com
    RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ nosteal.jpg [L]
</IfModule>
```